# How to improve this flawed doubly-linked list insert implementation efficiently?

Tags: c, linked-list

Say you have a simple DLL (doubly-linked list) implementation in C like so:

```
struct list {
  list* prev;
  list* next;
}
```

And you intend to implement elements in a `list` like this:

```
struct element {
  int value;
  struct list link;
}
```

With an `insert` operation like this:

```
void list_insert(struct list* list, struct list* element) {
    element->prev = list;
    element->next = list->next;
    list->next = element;
    element->next->prev = element;
}
```

And, lastly, you use your implementation like this:

```
// Initialize empty list
struct list mylist;
mylist.next = &mylist;
mylist.prev = &mylist;

// Initialize element
struct element e;
e.value = 42;

// Add element to list
list_insert(&mylist, &e.link);
```

This basically works well, but does not seem robust against the possibility of inserting `e` into `mylist` **twice**, unintentionally. What is a computationally efficient way of handling this, ideally in O(1) time?

Reference: The list design comes from the Wayland project. See [wayland-util.h](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/wayland/wayland/tree/src/wayland-util.h), and [wayland-util.c](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/wayland/wayland/tree/src/wayland-util.c).

Comment: Initialise your elements s.t. `prev = next = 0`, check elements to be inserted, if they in fact are unlinked elements.

Comment: Adding a static variable into a linked list seems unwise. Do all of your doubts disappear when you add a copy instead?

Comment: Embedding a `struct list` pointer in the `struct element` seems very dubious; you have to allocate memory for both an `element` and the `list` it uses.  If you keep `struct list` around, then you should have `struct list link;` in `struct element` for the benefit your sanity.  Most often, though, people simply embed `struct element *next; struct element *prev;` directly in `struct element`, doing without `struct list` altogether.  Amongst other problems, the elements of `struct list` are defined to point to `struct list` items, not `struct element` items — futzing around that is hard.

Comment: The second argument of `list_insert()` is declared to be `list*`, but you're calling it with `&e`, which is `element*`.

Comment: How are you not getting a compiler warning from that type error?

Comment: I don't see how this implementation can possibly work. When you follow the `next` or `prev` links to get to another list item, how do you get its value? You don't have any pointer from `list` to `element`.

Comment: Note that given your function definition `void list_insert(list* list, list* element)`, the line `list_insert(&mylist, &e);` should not compile (because you're trying to provide a `struct element *` where the function expects a `struct list *`).  If it compiles, it is because you don't have a prototype in scope before you call the function — in violation of the requirements of the C99 standard.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler @Barmar Thank you for pointing out the typo. I've fixed that to `list_insert(&mylist, &e.link);`.

Comment: @Barmar It's a clever trick, using `offsetof` to get the containing struct of the element's `link`.

Comment: Note that the Wayland code embeds `struct wl_list link;` (and not `struct wl_list *link;`) into the other structure.  Your code is seriously flawed because of that — you make the memory allocations far more complex.  I'm not entirely convinced that the technique shown is beneficial.  'Clever trick' in your eyes might be viewed as 'grotesque hack without good reason' by others, such as those coming after you to maintain your code.  There are occasions to use `offsetof`; I don't think this is one of them.  Not all the code on the Internet is worthy of emulation.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler A typo with the `link` member and the parameter types of the `insert` function. I fixed it.

Comment: You will also see `struct list { list *next, *prev; void *data }` where you then have a pointer to whatever *payload* your data happens to be. You will then have traditional list operations with only the additional requirement of allocating a nodes worth of data on each insert/add.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler For what it's worth, the Linux kernel uses this approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've combined and/or confused your list and list element structs. Lists typically have `head` and `next` elements rather than `next` and `prev`. The latter is usually for the *element* [and *not* the list].

And, unless you really wanted a "list of lists", the pointers within the list struct need to be pointers to the element and *not* lists. And, you wouldn't want to initialize the `head/tail` pointers within that list struct to point back to the same list.

Also, just because a list has *two* pointers does *not* make it a *doubly* linked list. It could be a *singly* linked list if the element *only* has a `next` pointer. To make it a *doubly* linked list, each element needs a `next` and `prev` pointer.

There's a bit more to it. I've created a cleaned up and annotated version of your program. Please note the other changes as well:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// element within list
typedef struct element {
    int value;                          // data value
    struct element *next;               // pointer to next element in list
    struct element *prev;               // pointer to previous element in list
} element_t;

// list of elements
typedef struct list {
    element_t *head;                    // pointer to first element in list
    element_t *tail;                    // pointer to last element in list
} list_t;

// new_element -- get new element
element_t *
new_element(int value)
{
    element_t *newptr;

    newptr = calloc(1,sizeof(element_t));

    if (newptr == NULL) {
        printf("new_element: malloc failure\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    newptr->value = value;

    return newptr;
}

// list_insert -- insert before list head
void
list_insert(list_t *list,element_t *newptr)
{
    element_t *head;

    head = list->head;

    newptr->prev = NULL;
    newptr->next = head;

    // insert at head of empty list
    if (head == NULL)
        list->tail = newptr;

    // insert at head of non-empty list
    else {
        newptr->next = head;
        head->prev = newptr;
    }

    // make new element the head of the list
    list->head = newptr;
}

// list_find_value -- find existing list element by value
element_t *
list_find_value(list_t *list,int value)
{
    element_t *curptr;

    // search for pre-existing element with the same value
    for (curptr = list->head;  curptr != NULL;  curptr = curptr->next) {
        if (curptr->value == value)
            break;
    }

    return curptr;
}

// list_insert_unique -- insert before list head
void
list_insert_unique(list_t *list,element_t *newptr)
{
    element_t *curptr;

    // search for pre-existing element with the same value
    curptr = list_find_value(list,newptr->value);

    // only insert if we did _not_ find one
    if (curptr == NULL)
        list_insert(list,newptr);
    else
        free(newptr);
}

// list_print -- print the list
void
list_print(list_t *list)
{
    element_t *curptr;

    printf("list_print:");

    // search for pre-existing element with the same value
    for (curptr = list->head;  curptr != NULL;  curptr = curptr->next)
        printf(" %d",curptr->value);

    printf("\n");
}

// list_print -- print the list in reverse order
void
list_rprint(list_t *list)
{
    element_t *curptr;

    printf("list_rprint:");

    // search for pre-existing element with the same value
    for (curptr = list->tail;  curptr != NULL;  curptr = curptr->prev)
        printf(" %d",curptr->value);

    printf("\n");
}

// main -- main program
int
main(void)
{
    list_t mylist;
    element_t *e;

    // initialize list
    mylist.head = NULL;
    mylist.tail = NULL;

    // Add unique element to list
    e = new_element(42);
    list_insert_unique(&mylist,e);

    e = new_element(23);
    list_insert_unique(&mylist,e);

    e = new_element(17);
    list_insert_unique(&mylist,e);

    // try to insert a duplicate
    e = new_element(17);
    list_insert_unique(&mylist,e);

    // try to insert a duplicate
    e = new_element(42);
    list_insert_unique(&mylist,e);

    // print list in order [checks the head/next pointers]
    list_print(&mylist);

    // print list in reverse order [checks the tail/prev pointers]
    list_rprint(&mylist);

    return 0;
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> But the question is asking for an improvement of the insert logic of the given list implementation.

You've been on SO long enough to know *not* to do a few things you've done in this question.

You posted code that was broken and wouldn't even compile. If it had been bug free, it should have been asked on CodeReview instead.

Because of this, the rest of the code became suspect. Now, after reviewing it, I surmise you wanted a doubly linked circular list. But, using `list` for the doubly linked list pointers is deceptive. It would have been more clear if this had been called `link`.

You asked about preventing duplicates [in **O(1)**]:

> does not seem robust against the possibility of inserting `e` into `mylist` **twice**, unintentionally.

This was not completely clear as to the criteria (i.e. pointer match, value match, or both).

You didn't provide any code to check for duplicates, just `list_insert` that did a insert at the head of the list.

> What is a computationally efficient way of handling this, ideally in O(1) time?

Insertion at head of list is **O(1)**, but *any* check for duplicates requires a full list scan, which is **O(n)**. This seemed to me to be basic. Not necessarily figuring out **O(n)**, but at least knowing it could *not* be **O(1)**

So, given all this, you shouldn't be surprised if your code gets refactored.

Even [now] knowing about the circular list of links, I wouldn't recommend doing it the way you did it, so I refactored. With your method, you "lose" access to `value`, so a scan for duplicate based on value becomes more problematic.

What I did was to *embed* the links into the element. This makes virtually all the code simpler. With the way you did it, then `element_t` is a sub-class that "inherits" from `link_t` (nee `list_t`). This would be okay for C++, but it makes the code a bit messier in C. I've created a version below that does it this way, just to show how much more complex the code becomes.

Perhaps most egregious of all, you edited your original code to "fix" the broken part. You should know to *not* do this, but append the fix to the bottom of your post as it makes answers no longer match the question.

Also, the Wayland code/link seems to have little matchup to your posted code. You didn't even try to relate the two in any specific way.

---

Here is a better `list_insert_unique` function:

```
// list_insert_unique -- insert before list head
void
list_insert_unique(list_t *list,element_t *newptr)
{
    int dupflg;
    element_t *curptr;

    // search for pre-existing element
    dupflg = 0;
    for (curptr = list->head;  curptr != NULL;  curptr = curptr->next) {
        // prevent list corruption
        if (curptr == newptr) {
            dupflg = -1;
            break;
        }

        // don't add duplicate values (we must continue to search for a
        // pointer match)
        if (curptr->value == value)
            dupflg = 1;
    }

    do {
        // we're trying to re-add the _same_ node
        if (dupflg < 0)
            break;

        // we're trying to add a different node but with an existing value
        if (dupflg) {
            free(newptr);
            break;
        }

        // only insert if we did _not_ find one
        list_insert(list,newptr);
    } while (0);
}
```

---

Here is a variation that preserves more of your original structure. It is *non*-circular, but that difference is relatively minor. Notice that it requires more "upcast" and/or "downcast" between the super class and the sub-class.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

// element within list
typedef struct link link_t;
struct link {
    link_t *next;                   // pointer to next link in list
    link_t *prev;                   // pointer to previous link in list
};

// list of elements
typedef struct list {
    link_t *head;                   // pointer to first element in list
    link_t *tail;                   // pointer to last element in list
} list_t;

// value types
typedef enum {
    VTYPE_INT = 1,
    VTYPE_FLT = 2
} vtype_t;

// value within list
typedef struct value {
    link_t link;                    // list linkage
    vtype_t type;                   // value type
    union {
        int int_value;              // data value
        double flt_value;           // data value
    };
} element_t;

#define ELEMENTOF(_eptr)    ((element_t *) (_eptr))
#define LINKOF(_vptr)       ((link_t *) (_vptr))

// new_element -- get new element
element_t *
new_element(vtype_t type,...)
{
    va_list ap;
    element_t *newptr;

    newptr = calloc(1,sizeof(element_t));

    if (newptr == NULL) {
        printf("new_element: malloc failure\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    newptr->type = type;

    va_start(ap,type);

    switch (type) {
    case VTYPE_INT:
        newptr->int_value = va_arg(ap,int);
        break;
    case VTYPE_FLT:
        newptr->flt_value = va_arg(ap,double);
        break;
    }

    va_end(ap);

    return newptr;
}

// list_insert -- insert before list head [O(1)]
void
list_insert(list_t *list,link_t *newptr)
{
    link_t *head;

    head = list->head;

    newptr->prev = NULL;
    newptr->next = head;

    // insert at head of empty list
    if (head == NULL)
        list->tail = newptr;

    // insert at head of non-empty list
    else {
        newptr->next = head;
        head->prev = newptr;
    }

    // make new element the head of the list
    list->head = newptr;
}

// list_find_value -- find existing list element by value [O(n)]
link_t *
list_find_value(list_t *list,element_t *newval,int *matchptr)
{
    int dupflg;
    element_t *curval;
    link_t *curptr;

    // search for pre-existing element with the same value
    dupflg = 0;
    for (curptr = list->head;  curptr != NULL;  curptr = curptr->next) {
        curval = ELEMENTOF(curptr);

        // don't allow the list to become corrupted
        if (curval == newval) {
            dupflg = -1;
            break;
        }

        // only compare values of similar type
        if (curval->type != newval->type)
            continue;

        switch (newval->type) {
        case VTYPE_INT:
            if (curval->int_value == newval->int_value)
                dupflg = 1;
            break;
        case VTYPE_FLT:
            if (curval->flt_value == newval->flt_value);
                dupflg = 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (matchptr != NULL)
        *matchptr = dupflg;

    return curptr;
}

// list_insert_unique -- insert before list head
void
list_insert_unique(list_t *list,element_t *newval)
{
    link_t *curptr;
    int dupflg;

    // search for pre-existing element with the same value
    curptr = list_find_value(list,newval,&dupflg);

    // only insert if we did _not_ find one
    do {
        // prevent double free
        if (dupflg < 0)
            break;

        if (dupflg) {
            free(newval);
            break;
        }

        list_insert(list,LINKOF(newval));
    } while (0);
}

// value_print -- print a single value
void
value_print(link_t *curptr)
{
    element_t *valptr;

    valptr = ELEMENTOF(curptr);

    switch (valptr->type) {
    case VTYPE_INT:
        printf(" I:%d",valptr->int_value);
        break;
    case VTYPE_FLT:
        printf(" F:%g",valptr->flt_value);
        break;
    }
}

// list_print -- print the list
void
list_print(list_t *list)
{
    link_t *curptr;

    printf("list_print:");

    for (curptr = list->head;  curptr != NULL;  curptr = curptr->next)
        value_print(curptr);

    printf("\n");
}

// list_rprint -- print the list in reverse order
void
list_rprint(list_t *list)
{
    link_t *curptr;

    printf("list_rprint:");

    for (curptr = list->tail;  curptr != NULL;  curptr = curptr->prev)
        value_print(curptr);

    printf("\n");
}

// main -- main program
int
main(void)
{
    list_t mylist;
    element_t *e;

    // initialize list
    mylist.head = NULL;
    mylist.tail = NULL;

    // Add unique element to list
    e = new_element(VTYPE_INT,42);
    list_insert_unique(&mylist,e);

    e = new_element(VTYPE_INT,23);
    list_insert_unique(&mylist,e);

    e = new_element(VTYPE_INT,17);
    list_insert_unique(&mylist,e);

    // try to insert a duplicate
    e = new_element(VTYPE_INT,17);
    list_insert_unique(&mylist,e);

    // try to insert a duplicate
    e = new_element(VTYPE_INT,42);
    list_insert_unique(&mylist,e);

    e = new_element(VTYPE_INT,67);
    list_insert_unique(&mylist,e);

    list_insert_unique(&mylist,e);

    // change the value [which also changes the list's value] and try to
    // insert
    e->int_value = 66;
    list_insert_unique(&mylist,e);

    // this is _not_ a duplicate because the type is different
    e = new_element(VTYPE_FLT,42.0);
    list_insert_unique(&mylist,e);

    // print list in order [checks the head/next pointers]
    list_print(&mylist);

    // print list in reverse order [checks the tail/prev pointers]
    list_rprint(&mylist);

    return 0;
}
```

---

**UPDATE #2:**

> Super follow-up, thank you. Yes, I'm aware of the original post's errors and edited them for correctness; and of the flaws of the provided implementation.

Okay, I *think* I've figured out the best of [our :-)] two worlds.

First, it depends upon what a duplicate means. Originally, I took that to be a duplicate *value*. My *updated* `list_insert_unique` had to do a full scan to the end, even if it found a *value* match halfway, because it had to finish the scan to find a duplicate *pointer* match. This forced an **O(n)**

However, if you didn't/don't mind duplicate values, and merely wanted to check for a new node already being on the list (i.e. allowing duplicate values but preventing list corruption), this *can* be done in **O(1)** by using a different detection method.

I've split my *updated* `list_insert_unique` into two functions:

`list_insert_unique_value` which is very similar. It is **O(n)** *worst* case, but is **O(n/2)** on average. This is because the value scan can *now* stop *immediately* upon finding a value match.

`list_insert_unique_pointer` which just checks for the new node already being on the list and is always **O(1)**

This works because it assumes something like my `new_element` function that does `calloc` to set the link pointers to NULL. It would *not* work in your original `main` without doing `e.next = NULL; e.prev = NULL;` before calling `list_insert`.

Below is my original version with these changes. I still recommend the simplicity of embedding the links into `element_t` but this can be [easily] adapted to the super-class/derived-class model of my second example [similar to your original].

*Side note:* I've done quite a few doubly linked implementations over the years, using *both* styles and I prefer embedding when possible. Actually, I have multiple separate code bases and have used the "inheritance" model in one and the "embed" model in another. I did this to experiment with speed, ease-of-use, detection of list corruption or link corruption, etc. Although the linux kernel uses circular lists, I never have, mainly because I couldn't find a use case for making them circular in my own code--YMMV.

The code below is [still] non-circular, but can also be adapted to circular lists. The `for` loops would have to change to something like:

```
for (curptr = list->head->next;  curptr != head;  curptr = curptr->next)
```

For my own code, I [would] usually hide such ugliness in a CPP macro like:

```
for (FORALL_FORWARD(list,curptr))
```

Anyway, here it is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// element within list
typedef struct element {
    int value;                          // data value
    struct element *next;               // pointer to next element in list
    struct element *prev;               // pointer to previous element in list
} element_t;

// list of elements
typedef struct list {
    element_t *head;                    // pointer to first element in list
    element_t *tail;                    // pointer to last element in list
} list_t;

// new_element -- get new element
element_t *
new_element(int value)
{
    element_t *newptr;

    newptr = calloc(1,sizeof(element_t));

    if (newptr == NULL) {
        printf("new_element: malloc failure\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    newptr->value = value;

    return newptr;
}

// list_insert -- insert before list head
void
list_insert(list_t *list,element_t *newptr)
{
    element_t *head;

    head = list->head;

    newptr->prev = NULL;
    newptr->next = head;

    // insert at head of empty list
    if (head == NULL)
        list->tail = newptr;

    // insert at head of non-empty list
    else {
        newptr->next = head;
        head->prev = newptr;
    }

    // make new element the head of the list
    list->head = newptr;
}

// list_insert_unique_pointer -- insert before list head [O(1)]
void
list_insert_unique_pointer(list_t *list,element_t *newptr)
{
    int dupflg;

    // check for being on the list -- works for both circular/non-circular
    // NOTE: for circular, this can be reduced to:
    //   dupflg = (newptr->prev != NULL)
    dupflg = (newptr == list->head) || (newptr->prev != NULL);
    //dupflg = -dupflg;

    do {
        // we're trying to re-add the _same_ node -- we'd corrupt the list
        if (dupflg)
            break;

        // only insert if we did _not_ find one
        list_insert(list,newptr);
    } while (0);
}

// list_insert_unique_value -- insert before list head [O(n)]
void
list_insert_unique_value(list_t *list,element_t *newptr)
{
    int dupflg;
    element_t *curptr;
    int value;

    curptr = list->head;

    // check for being on the list -- works for both circular/non-circular
    dupflg = (newptr == curptr) || (newptr->prev != NULL);
    dupflg = -dupflg;

    // search for pre-existing element with the same value
    value = newptr->value;
    for (;  curptr != NULL;  curptr = curptr->next) {
        if (dupflg)
            break;
        dupflg = (curptr->value == value);
    }

    do {
        // we're trying to re-add the _same_ node -- we'd corrupt the list
        if (dupflg < 0)
            break;

        // we're trying to add a different node but with an existing value
        if (dupflg) {
            free(newptr);
            break;
        }

        // only insert if we did _not_ find one
        list_insert(list,newptr);
    } while (0);
}

// list_print -- print the list
void
list_print(list_t *list)
{
    element_t *curptr;

    printf("list_print:");

    for (curptr = list->head;  curptr != NULL;  curptr = curptr->next)
        printf(" %d",curptr->value);

    printf("\n");
}

// list_print -- print the list in reverse order
void
list_rprint(list_t *list)
{
    element_t *curptr;

    printf("list_rprint:");

    for (curptr = list->tail;  curptr != NULL;  curptr = curptr->prev)
        printf(" %d",curptr->value);

    printf("\n");
}

// main -- main program
int
main(void)
{
    list_t mylist;
    element_t *e;

    // initialize list
    mylist.head = NULL;
    mylist.tail = NULL;

    // Add unique element to list
    e = new_element(42);
    list_insert_unique_value(&mylist,e);

    // try to corrupt the list
    list_insert_unique_pointer(&mylist,e);

    e = new_element(23);
    list_insert_unique_value(&mylist,e);

    // try to corrupt the list
    list_insert_unique_pointer(&mylist,e);

    e = new_element(17);
    list_insert_unique_value(&mylist,e);

    // try to insert a duplicate
    e = new_element(17);
    list_insert_unique_value(&mylist,e);

    // try to insert a duplicate
    e = new_element(42);
    list_insert_unique_value(&mylist,e);

    // print list in order [checks the head/next pointers]
    list_print(&mylist);

    // print list in reverse order [checks the tail/prev pointers]
    list_rprint(&mylist);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I know that the implementation of the list can be different, and I appreciate your answer! But the question is asking for an improvement of the insert logic of the given list implementation.

Comment: Super follow-up, thank you. Yes, I'm aware of the original post's errors and  edited them for correctness; and of the flaws of the provided implementation.

Comment: It would be worth explaining the difference between a *head/tail* list and a *circular* list (which it appeared was the original intent with *next* and *prev* pointing back to the first node.) They are essentially two distinct methods of handling the beginning and end of the list where the *circular* list has the benefit of being able to traverse from any node, to any node without the need of iterating separate pointers in different directions.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Yes, agreed. I'll add something. I knew the mechanics, but was trying to think of an actual use case that benefits (i.e. a real work practical example--perhaps, the kernel). Also, a null terminated list can be traversed as circular using two for loops, or a single one if one sets up an iterator function [and puts a "current" pointer into `list_t`, which I've done before]. But, tomorrow, as it's past my bedtime here :-)